# How to enable the "United States-International" keyboard layout in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-layout

I want to enable the "United States-International" keyboard layout in Windows 8, but the option for it seems to be missing. Is there any way to enable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to Control Panel.
2. Under **Clock, Language and Region**, click **Change input methods**.
3. Click **Options** to the right of your language.
4. Click **Add an input method**.
5. Select **United States-International / Touch keyboard layout**. (I'm not sure what "touch" means here.)

Comment: Future note for anyone else: you can quickly switch between the inputs with Windows key + Space bar

Comment: Another note, if you only have the Language English installed, you don't have the option to choose the United States-International keyboard.  A work around to get it, is to install another Language (I used German), you don't have to switch to it, just installing it adds the keyboard layout to the choices of keyboard layouts.